# Contact forms WP plugin not showing SUBMIT button

Tags: css, wordpress, forms, button, contacts

I've got contact forms plugin on my wp website but it stopped showing submit button. Seems some glitch in css, any ideas?
http://www.lukask.cz/individualni-konzultace/

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the button on the form like this:

```
[submit "Send"]
```

Answer (score 1):

For some reason, the submit button is wrapped in `<noscript></noscript>` tag:

```
<noscript>
    <button type='submit' id='ufo-field-id-3369' name='id-3369' >Domluvit konzultaci</button>
</noscript>
```

Try to find the source of `<noscript>` and remove it.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks guys, based on your tips I found out there is common problem with JS and plugin even has simple solution in settings "Fix submit button". Hope it can help others.